# How to update JSON using JQ and get the updated value

Tags: json, updates, increment, jq

I have some data in JSON which I want to edit using JQ.

- It's a list of persons.
- Each person can have one or more `mobile`.
- Each `mobile` has a `number` (which is obviously unique) and no. of `calls` made.
- Also person keep track of `total` calls (sum of calls for each mobile they have)

*I have tried to use self explanatory variables here. Please let me know if the data is not clear enough.*

```js
[
  {
    "name": "Person1",
    "mobiles": [{
      "number": "11111",
      "calls": 2
    },{
      "number": "22222",
      "calls": 3
    }],
    "total": 5
  },
  {
    "name": "Person2",
    "mobiles": [{
      "number": "33333",
      "calls": 1
    },{
      "number": "44444",
      "calls": 2
    },{
      "number": "55555",
      "calls": 1
    }],
    "total": 4
  }
]
```

What I want is, given a mobile number and no. of calls made for that mobile on a particular day, update the json (update both the individual counter and the total)

Eg. Let's say for number `444444` calls made are 5, then the final json should be

```js
[
  {
    "name": "Person1",
    "mobiles": [{
      "number": "11111",
      "calls": 2
    },{
      "number": "22222",
      "calls": 3
    }],
    "total": 5
  },
  {
    "name": "Person2",
    "mobiles": [{
      "number": "33333",
      "calls": 1
    },{
      "number": "44444",
      "calls": 7 // previous value was 2, added 5 more
    },{
      "number": "55555",
      "calls": 1
    }],
    "total": 9 // previous total was 4, added 5 more
  }
]
```

### What I have tried so far

I am able to update the `total` calls but not the individual calls for the given number

`map(select(.mobiles[].number == "44444").total = .total + 5)` gives

```js
[
  {
    "name": "Person1",
    "mobiles": [
      {
        "number": "11111",
        "calls": 2
      },
      {
        "number": "22222",
        "calls": 3
      }
    ],
    "total": 5
  },
  {
    "name": "Person2",
    "mobiles": [
      {
        "number": "33333",
        "calls": 1
      },
      {
        "number": "44444",
        "calls": 2 // How do I update this
      },
      {
        "number": "55555",
        "calls": 1
      }
    ],
    "total": 9 // This is correct
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update the relevant "calls" along the lines you were exploring:

```
map( (.mobiles[] | select(.number == $number) | .calls) += $incr)
```

where the values of $number and $incr can (for example) be specified on the command line, e.g.

```
jq --arg number 44444 --argjson incr 5 -f update.jq input.json
```

To update the relevant "total", you could use `any/2`:

```
map( if any(.mobiles[]; .number == $number) 
     then .total += $incr
     else . 
     end)
```

You could chain these two together, either literally, or (presumably more efficiently) by combining the two filters into a single `map`.  For readability and maintainability, you might also want to define helper functions (i.e., using `def`).

Comment: Thanks for the tip about using `def`. Didn't know about that. Your solution works perfectly. Accepting as correct answer.